# Java MIDI External device transmit to sequencer's receiver

Tags: java, midi, javasound

I am having some trouble transmitting data to my sequencer's receiver from my external device.  I am having no problems transmitting it to any other receiver.  For an example:

I have these two classes :

```
public class TestData {
    private Receiver receiver;

    public TestData(Receiver receiver)
    {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public void sendTestData() throws InvalidMidiDataException
    {
        ShortMessage shortMessage = new ShortMessage();
        shortMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 50, 127);
        receiver.send(shortMessage, 123);
        shortMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, 50, 0);
        receiver.send(shortMessage, 124);
        shortMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_ON, 0, 51, 127);
        receiver.send(shortMessage, 125);
        shortMessage.setMessage(ShortMessage.NOTE_OFF, 0, 51, 0);
        receiver.send(shortMessage, 126);
    }

}
```

and

```
public class MidiInputReceiver implements Receiver {
    public String name;
    Map<Byte, String> commandMap = new HashMap<Byte, String>();

    public MidiInputReceiver(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        commandMap.put((byte)-112, "Note On");
        commandMap.put((byte) -128, "Note Off");
        commandMap.put((byte) -48, "Channel Pressure");
        commandMap.put((byte) -80, "Continuous Controller");
    }
    public void send(MidiMessage msg, long timeStamp) {
        System.out.println("midi received");
        System.out.println("Timestamp: "  + timeStamp);
        byte[] b = msg.getMessage();

        if(b[0] != -48){
            //System.out.println("Message length: " + msg.getLength());
            System.out.println("Note command: " + commandMap.get(b[0]));
            System.out.println("Which note: " + b[1]);
            System.out.println("Note pressure: " + b[2]);
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }else{
            //System.out.println("Message length: " + msg.getLength());
            System.out.println("Note command: " + commandMap.get(b[0]));
            System.out.println("Note Pressure: " + b[1]);
            System.out.println("---------------------");
        }
    }
    public void close() {}
}
```

This works fine:

```
sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.open();
Sequence myseq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 10);
Track newTrack = myseq.createTrack();
sequencer.setSequence(myseq);
sequencer.setTickPosition(0);
sequencer.recordEnable(newTrack, -1);

TestData testData = new TestData(sequencer.getReceiver())
sequencer.startRecording();
testData.sendTestData();
```

and this works as well:

```
MidiDevice device;
MidiDevice.Info[] infos;
infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[0]);
device.open();

Transmitter conTrans = device.getTransmitter();
conTrans.setReceiver(new MidiInputDevice("Test"));
```

So the controller has no problem sending to my custom receiver.  And the sequencer's receiver has no problem receiving from my TestData Class.  But the following (Transmitting from my external controller to my sequencer's receiver does not work):

```
MidiDevice device;
MidiDevice.Info[] infos;
infos = MidiSystem.getMidiDeviceInfo();
device = MidiSystem.getMidiDevice(infos[0]);
device.open();

sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
sequencer.open();
Sequence myseq = new Sequence(Sequence.PPQ, 10);
Track newTrack = myseq.createTrack();
sequencer.setSequence(myseq);
sequencer.setTickPosition(0);
sequencer.recordEnable(newTrack, -1);

Transmitter conTrans = device.getTransmitter();
conTrans.setReceiver(sequencer.getReceiver());
sequencer.startRecording();
```

Is there anything that I am missing?

Edit:
Okay I can see that the track actually is receiving the MidiEvents.  I think the issue is timing.  The tick numbers seem very high so when I go to play it back, I think it is just waiting a really, really long time to playback an event that happened in the beginning of the recording.  I think this has something to do with syncing my device to my sequencer but I'm not sure what my SyncModes should be set to.

Answer (score 2):

Okay I figured out a way to work around this.  This seems to be working well.  Before any playback, I adjust all of the ticks based on the first tick.  This would need to be done for every track.

Like so:

```
int eventSize = sequencer.getSequence().getTracks()[0].size();
MidiEvent firstEvent = sequencer.getSequence().getTracks()[0].get(0);
long baseTime = firstEvent.getTick();

for(int i = 0; i < eventSize; i++){
    MidiEvent event = sequencer.getSequence().getTracks()[0].get(i);
    event.setTick(event.getTick() - baseTime);
}
```

Comment: +1, thanks.. but, do you have news related to this "problem"?